# build custom corpus with labels from text documents using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am following the tutorial to build custom corpus with ntlk. This is an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import nltk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 200
%matplotlib inline

corpus = ['t_3_0 v_0_17 v_1_20 v_2_78 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2',
          't_3_1 v_0_144 v_1_17 v_2_20 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2',
          't_3_2 v_0_143 v_1_233 v_2_238 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2',
          't_3_3 v_0_20 v_1_253 v_2_275 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2',
          't_3_4 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_90 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2',
          't_3_59 v_0_233 v_1_222 v_2_51 v_3_52 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3',
          't_3_60 v_0_238 v_1_11 v_2_137 v_3_143 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3',
          't_3_61 v_0_238 v_1_111 v_2_214 v_3_94 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3',
          't_3_62 v_0_238 v_1_111 v_2_214 v_3_97 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3',
          't_3_63 v_0_238 v_1_137 v_2_214 v_3_51 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3'
             
]
labels = ['block_1', 'block_1', 'block_1', 'block_1', 'block_1',
          'block_2', 'block_2', 'block_2', 'block_2', 'block_2']

corpus = np.array(corpus)
corpus_df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': corpus, 
                          'Category': labels})
corpus_df = corpus_df[['Document', 'Category']]
corpus_df
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Document                                                Category
0   t_3_0 v_0_17 v_1_20 v_2_78 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2            block_1
1   t_3_1 v_0_144 v_1_17 v_2_20 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2           block_1
2   t_3_2 v_0_143 v_1_233 v_2_238 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2         block_1
3   t_3_3 v_0_20 v_1_253 v_2_275 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2          block_1
4   t_3_4 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_90 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2          block_1
5   t_3_59 v_0_233 v_1_222 v_2_51 v_3_52 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3  block_2
6   t_3_60 v_0_238 v_1_11 v_2_137 v_3_143 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3 block_2
7   t_3_61 v_0_238 v_1_111 v_2_214 v_3_94 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3 block_2
8   t_3_62 v_0_238 v_1_111 v_2_214 v_3_97 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3 block_2
9   t_3_63 v_0_238 v_1_137 v_2_214 v_3_51 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3 block_2
```

What I would like to do is instead of hardcoding corpus and labels, I would prefer to read each line from txt documents and assign labels automatically using the name of the file. For example:

```
corpus = ['block_1.txt', 'block_2.txt', 'block_3.txt', 'block_4.txt']

labels = ['block_1', 'block_2', 'block_3', 'block_4']

corpus = np.array(corpus)
corpus_df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': corpus, 
                          'Category': labels})
corpus_df = corpus_df[['Document', 'Category']]
corpus_df
```

The example of desirable output would look like this:

```
    Document                                                Category
0   t_3_0 v_0_17 v_1_20 v_2_78 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2            block_1
1   t_3_1 v_0_144 v_1_17 v_2_20 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2           block_1
2   t_3_2 v_0_143 v_1_233 v_2_238 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2         block_1
...
```

I would appreciate any suggestions and help!

Thank you!
Olha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the answer. Basically, I created a list of tuples and then categorize each line.

```
transactions = []
with open('block_1.txt', 'r') as block1, open('block_2.txt', 'r') as block2, open('block_3.txt', 'r') as block3, open('t_block_4.txt', 'r') as block4:
    transactions = ([(transaction, 'block_1') for transaction in block1.readlines()] + [(transaction, 'block_2') for transaction in block2.readlines()] + [(transaction, 'block_3') for transaction in block3.readlines()] + [(transaction, 'block_4') for transaction in block4.readlines()])

#transactions

corpus = np.array(transactions)
corpus_df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': [i[0] for i in transactions], 
                          'Category': [i[1] for i in transactions]})
corpus_df = corpus_df[['Document', 'Category']]
corpus_df
```